# Crystal Report- Set value as Zero (formula)

Tags: crystal-reports

if database field value null, the crystal report should preview the value as Zero.

Ex: One of the Database.Feildname value null.. When crystal report preview nothing..So i want to set it value as Zero (0).. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

That's an indication your field is not a number. So change to:

```
IF IsNull({yourField}) Then "0"  ELSE {yourField}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal has an option to set NULL values to default but I think that's not a good practice.
Instead, use a formula such as: `IF IsNull({yourField}) Then 0  ELSE {yourField}`

Comment: It's not working my bro..It show error message in cyrstal Report Viewer "A number is required here. Details: errorKind"